# Passar valores do FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase

Como faço para passar um objeto ao clicar em um item da recycler view sendo que estou usando um `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`?

Do jeito que estou fazendo está dando certo, crio uma lista, e no método `populateViewHolder` eu adiciono o objeto que quero passar em uma lista, então no método onclick eu passo o objeto de acordo com o `position`

```
noteAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Note, NoteHolder>(Note.class, R.layout.note_item, NoteHolder.class, dbRef) {

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(NoteHolder viewHolder, Note model, final int position) {
                viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                viewHolder.setContent(model.getContent());
                Log.d(TAG, "!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                model.setId(getRef(position).getKey());
                noteList.add(model);

                viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent it = new Intent(v.getContext(), NoteDetailActivity.class);
                        it.putExtra(MainFragment.NOTE_PARCE, noteList.get(position));
                        startActivity(it);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

Porém isso tem um problema... `populateViewHolder` é chamado sempre que o usuário usar o scroll do `RecyclerView`, ou seja, é adicionado na lista os mesmos valores sempre que o scroll é usado!

Qual o melhor meio para passar o objeto para a outra Activity?

Ou como fazer para não serem adicionados os mesmos objetos sempre que o usuário usar o scroll?

**UPDATE:**

Eu fiz isso dentro do `populateViewHolder`:

```
if(noteList.size()<this.getItemCount()) {
     noteList.add(model);
}
```

Soluciona o problema de ficar adicionando objetos repetidos, mas tem um porém, sempre que o adapter for atualizado, ele adicionará mais objetos... O Firebase armazena os dados em cache, quando tiver online ele envia para base no firebase, se os dados estão em cache e eu remover todos no console do firebase, o List não é atualizado, continua com os dados que estavam em cache, mesmo que eu adicione novos.
Como limpar o List quando os dados mudarem?
Tentei no `onDataChanged()`, porém ele é chamado sempre que um valor é adicionado no adapter, ou seja, assim ele sempre limpará toda a lista, mesmo se for apenas um valor adicionado e não todos removidos (como fiz no exemplo)!

```
@Override
protected void onDataChanged() {
  super.onDataChanged();
  noteList.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problema resolvido, fiz assim:

```
@Override
protected void onDataChanged() {
super.onDataChanged();
  if(getItemCount()==0) {
      noteList.clear();
  }
}
```